# Open specific activity using FCM when notification clicked in background not working

Tags: android, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM to push notification. I am passing intent to launch new activity when notification is clicked.when app is in foreground,app works fine and intent launch new activity, but when app is in background, it does not launch new activity but launch instance of default activity.

I used 2 functions, the first one is used when i receive a notification from the foreground, and the second is used when i receive a notification from the background.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        if (remoteMessage.getData().isEmpty())

// when app is in foreground
            ShowNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        else

// when app is in background

            ShowNotification(remoteMessage.getData());

    }
```

the function used in the background :

```
    public void ShowNotification(Map<String, String> data) {

        String title = data.get("title").toString();
        Log.d(TAG, "Title : " +title);
        String body = data.get("body").toString();
        Log.d(TAG, "Body : " + body);

        String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
/*
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
*/

        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        notificationIntent.putExtra("title", title);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("body", body);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("date", currentDateTimeString);
        notificationIntent.setAction(title);
        notificationIntent.setAction(body);
        notificationIntent.setAction(currentDateTimeString);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.example.firebasecloudmessaging.test";

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,"Notification",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

            notificationChannel.setDescription("Hamza");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0,1000,500,1000});
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentInfo("Infos");

        notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(),notificationBuilder.build());

    }
```

Comment: in pendingIntent you are passing notificationIntent. is this the activity you want to open when notificaion is clicked?

Comment: no, i want to open this activity :         Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);